# Angularjs view updates properly in Chrome but not in Safari

Tags: angularjs

I'm just experimenting in Angularjs for the first time and have struck the following. Just to confuse everyone I'm doing it in coffeescript.

I have the following controller;

```
testApp = angular.module('testme', ['ngRoute'])

testApp.config ["$routeProvider", ($routeProvider) -> 
    $routeProvider.when('/',
        templateUrl: 'invoice_list.html'
        ).otherwise redirectTo: '/'
]

testApp.controller 'InvoicesController', ($scope, $http, $filter) ->
    $scope.category = 'Incomplete'
    $scope.invoices = []
    $scope.invoice_count = {}
    $scope.$watch 'category', -> #when invoice category select changes
        if !$scope.invoice_count[$scope.category] #unless we have already gotten this category from the server
            $http.get('api/invoices?status=' + $scope.category).success (data) -> #get list of invoices for that category from server
                invoiceList = $scope.invoices.concat data.invoices #add it to the existing array of invoices
                idList = []
                result = []
                invoiceList.forEach (invoice) ->
                    if idList.indexOf(invoice.id) == -1
                        result.push invoice
                        idList.push invoice.id
                $scope.invoices = result #and remove duplicates using invoice.id as indicator of uniqueness
                $scope.invoice_count[$scope.category] = data.meta.counts[$scope.category] #then update invoice_count for the category
```

and here is a cut-down version of my view;

```
<html ng-app='testme'>
  <head>
    <title>angular test</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller='InvoicesController'>
    <script id='invoice_list.html' type='text/ng-template'>
      <li class='list-group-item' ng-repeat='invoice in invoices | filter: category:true'>
        <div class='invoice-list-total'>{{invoice.total | currency}}</div>
        <div class='invoice-list-name'>{{invoice.patient.full_name}}</div>
        <div class='invoice-list-date'>{{(invoice.invoice_date | date:'dd/MM/yy') || '&nbsp;'}}</div>
      </li>
    </script>
    <ul class='list-group voffset30'>
      <li class='list-group-item invoice-list-header'>
        <select id="category" name="category" ng-model="category">
          <option value="Incomplete">Incomplete</option>
          <option value="Complete">Complete</option>
          <option value="Sent">Sent</option>
          <option value="Paid">Paid</option>
        </select>
        <span class='badge'>{{invoice_count[category]}}</span>
      </li>
      <div class='ng-view'></div>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do is retrieve a list of invoices from a server (Rails) and display them. There are 4 categories of server. When the page first loads the default option of incomplete is selected in the select box. My controller retrieves the list of incomplete invoices from the server and populates the invoices array with them for display. They will then be displayed in the ng-view which displays the list of invoices filtered by category. I also update the invoice_count object with a count of the invoices that was provided by the server as a key/value object (e.g. 'Incomplete':15). This count is intended to be displayed in the span with the class 'badge'. I hope I have explained this reasonably well.

Now this works *perfectly* in Chrome and I was giving myself a very big pat on the back for achieving something in Angular for the first time. I then tried it in Safari though and was rapidly disappointed. After I change the select option, the span.badge showing the invoice category count disappears! As soon as I interact with the page in any way (even clicking whitespace) it is updated with the correct result. This occurs in iOS Safari as well. I can't figure this out by myself. I thought it might be a $scope.$apply() thing, but adding this into the controller just results in an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Select is notoriously problematic in angular, partly due to cross browser rendering differences. It's possible that this is a bug in the framework. If you can produce a minimal example that shows the difference, you should post a bug on the angular issue tracker.

Comment: OK, I'll spend some time in jsfiddle. Disappointing if I've found a bug on my first adventure with the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this just for reference - I had almost exactly the same problem in  Safari - a badge wouldn't show up in Safari after http updates. Your JS code is however not syntactically exactly the same, but others might find this thread for similar reasons as I did and could find my solution appropriate.

My badge counter actually showed the `length` of an array I iterated over - the array iteration displayed fine in Safari after http updates, but the array length badge was still not updated.

**Btw** - if I inspect the DOM I see the `class="badge ng-binding"`. Remove the ng-binding (`class="badge"`) and the counter appear.

**My solution:** I originally actually deleted the array before fetching new data, in order to make the update visually obvious for users. If I instead of deleting the JS variable set it to an empty array, the badge counter also worked in Safari.

So try avoid deleting variables, and update them as few times as possible for Safari compatibility.

br,
Jens